# Edit screensaver location in GPO with script

Tags: powershell, group-policy, automation

Unfortunately our company still changes its screensaver every 15 days.
Someone from HR makes the new screensaver, drops it on a share and we IT copy it to SYSVOL and change the path to the new screensaver in GPO.

We would like to automate this process.

I there a way to update the path in the GPO with a script?

I know the setting is part of the `controlpaneldisplay.admx`, the setting name is `Force specific screen saver` and the regkey is set in `HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop!SCRNSAVE.EXE`

Has someone managed to edit the screensaver with a script before?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the same filename for each screensaver? When you get a new one simply delete or archive the old one and drop the new one in it's place. That way you don't need to edit your Group Policy at all.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible because the current screensaver is in-use and can not be deleted / overwritten.